# Ruby encrypting passwords to be stored in config file

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am looking for suggestions on how I can encrypt a password that will be stored in a config file so that it will not be in clear text?  I will also need a way to decrypt the password after it is read in by the script? script is a simple ftp script and config file will be very simple containing host and user credentials.  I am using yaml for the config file.

```
host = 'ftp.someftp.com'
id = 'jdoe'
pw = 'encrypted password'
```

If someone can point me in the right direction I would be most appreciative.  There must be a simple way to do this or a gem out there for doing so.

Thanks
MM

Comment: Give the OP a break. At this point he's a new user and hasn't had a chance to accept any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For encryption you can also use the [bcrypt gem](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby) which is widely used and practical to use. Make sure you have bcrypt installed on your system otherwise the gem won't work.

To see how it works check out its Readme, especially the [How to use bcrypt-ruby in general](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby#how-to-use-bcrypt-ruby-in-general) section.

Comment: can't decrypt with bcrypt

Comment: well, it hs to be encrypted with bcrypt in the first place, @PeterHawkins. There are legion of other encryption methods that can certainly not be decrypted with bcrypt.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [OpenSSL](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html) library. Look for password-based encryption methods, such as AES. You also need a way to write the encrypted binary data as ASCII, in your configuration file.

Caveat: if you can encrypt it, anyone who can read the script can also see how you did it, and then they can decrypt it. So this is ok as long as you're protecting the passwords from casual/accidental viewing only.

Comment: "if you can encrypt it, anyone who can read the script can also see how you did it, and then they can decrypt it." Exactly. Locking down the file's permissions is the best way to deal with the problem. Make the file not readable by anyone but the app's owner and only allow running the app as that owner, and the problem is solved.

Comment: The fun thing about that, is that in most cases, if it were enough, then it'd have been enough to lock down the permissions on the config file. Security is like boxes inside boxes inside boxes...

Comment: Running on windows and compiling script to an executable so I am not overly concerned with the folks I have being able to figure it out from the compiled executable.  I expect to get ripped into for that statement.

Comment: Hehe, that's a good expectation. :-) Executables can be disassembled. Like i tried to say, it's a compromise. Encrypting it will protect your passwords from most people, but not from the Mafia or the CIA. On the other hand, those guys have other ways to get your passwords, which don't necessarily include decryption. :-) At least, make your password random, so it doesn't stand out if someone reads the strings in your executable.